# Maximum call stack size exceeded - reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm a beginner at `react.js`.

I got this error:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

full error output in my browser chrome console:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at warning (bundle.js:1977)
at callHook (bundle.js:11215)
at emitEvent (bundle.js:11225)
at Object.onBeforeMountComponent (bundle.js:11502)
at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:13853)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:7622)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:7509)
at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:13856)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:7622)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:7509)
```

my codes:

```
var React=require('react');
var ReactDOM=require('react-dom');

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                < Header />,
                < Main />,
                < Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Header extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Header>
                <nav>
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                </nav>
            </Header>
        );
    }
}

class Main extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p> text 1</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Footer extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <h2>Footer</h2>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/> ,  document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: it means somewhere you are  calling a function that is calling another function and so on until the stack memory is exceeded

Comment: try to use  setTimeout( yourFunc , 1) to fix error .

Comment: You are trying to render self in `Header`. It will cause infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this ,

```
class Header extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Header>
                <nav>
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                </nav>
            </Header>
        );
    } 
}
```

To

```
class Header extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                </nav>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have `<Header>` tag inside the header component so that is causing an infinite loop i think..try removing this..you are calling header in the `App` component and which ids again calling the header component and so on.
You should just render like this

```
class Header extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
            <nav>
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </nav>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a recursive call by rendering `Header` in `Header`.

Change your code to use `header` for real html tags:

```
class Header extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                </nav>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```